# How to implement third party authentication in gramex

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, gramex

I am trying to build a simple gramex application. where i need to authorize user from linkedin, outlook, Github & gmail.

Please share some code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url:
  auth/github:
    pattern: /$YAMLURL/github
    handler: OAuth2
    kwargs:
      # Create app at https://code.gramener.com/admin/applications/
      client_id: 'YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID'      # https://github.com/settings/connections/applications/
      client_secret: 'YOUR_APP_SECRET_ID'
      authorize:
        url: 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize'
        scope: [repo, gist, user]
      access_token:
        url: 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token'
        body:
          grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      user_info:
        url: 'https://api.github.com/user'
        headers:
          Authorization: 'Bearer {access_token}'
        redirect:
          query: next
          header: Referer
          url: .
```

This is the code snippet for Github with OAuth2

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps

- **client_id**: Create an app with the OAuth2 provider to get this ID
- **client_secret**: Create an app with the OAuth2 provider to get this ID
- **authorize**: Authorization endpoint configuration

  - url: Authorization endpoint URL
  - scope: an optional a list of scopes that determine what you can access
- **access_token**: Access token endpoint configuration

  - url: Access token endpoint URL
- **user_info**: Optional user information API endpoint

  - url: API endpoint to fetch URL
  - headers: optional dict containing HTTP headers to pass to user info URL. e.g.
  - Authorization: 'Bearer {access_token}'. Default: {User-Agent: Gramex/}